# How do I update a key value in Firebase's Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a users field in a real-time database with around 100k records, each of them containing a key value field inside that I need to be changed from true to false, is there an automated way ( and I guess there should be ) to change that field globally for each user? Thank you.

Comment: Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please also indicate the exact filed you need to update.

Comment: google cloud firestore and firebase-realtime-database are 2 separate things as per your question it looks like you have problem with realtime-db so please remove the google-cloud-firestore tag

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific operation to perform an update a properties under multiple nodes. You will have to update each of them individually.

Since to write a node you will need to know the exact path to that node, this may require that you read the data first. In which case you'd need to:

1. Read the parent node.
2. Loop through its child nodes.
3. Update each of them in turn.